# Couchbase Lite Swift - Indexing on optional property

Tags: swift, indexing, couchbase-lite

I need to index a property in a `Couchbase Lite` database, and the property is optional, i.e. not present in all documents. I wanted to know if this kind of indexing is supported in `Couchbase Lite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It is entirely possible to put an index on a property that is not present in all documents or a property whose value is `nil` in some documents.

Documents with properties like that might be represented in Swift, as Optionals.